# If $p(x)$ be the polynomial left as remainder when $x^{2019}-1$ is divided by $x^6+1$. What is the remainder left when $p(x)$ is divided by $x-3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, divisibility

If $p(x)$ be the polynomial left as remainder when $x^{2019}-1$ is divided by $x^6+1$. What is the remainder left when $p(x)$ is divided by $x-3$?

It is obvious that remainder is a constant. How do I solve it?

Comment: Note that $(x^6+1)(x^6-1)=x^{12}-1$ so $p(x)$ is also the remainder of $x^{2019-12\lfloor 2019/12\rfloor}-1$ divided by $x^6+1$.  So you can work out the value.

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry. I did not get the point. can you explain little more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers give cooler results, but keeping in mind the algebra-precalculus tag:

$$x^{2019}-1=(x^6+1)(x^{2013}-x^{2007}+\cdots+(-1)^kx^{2013-6k}+\cdots+x^9-x^3)+(x^3-1)$$
$$\therefore x^3-1=(x-3)(x^2+3x+9)+26$$

Comment: Note that by the polynomial remainder theorem, you do not need to rewrite $x^3 - 1$ as when $x = 3$, the $(x - 3)$ term becomes $0$ and everything except the remainder term vanishes. Therefore, simply calculating $p(3)$ is enough.

Comment: @Chrystomath I think that (-1)^k will be replaced by (-1)^{k+1}

Comment: I meant 2013 but wrote 2019. Will correct it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Let $t=x^3$, then we need to find a remainder if we divide $t^{673}-1$ with $t^2+1$. Write:

$$t^{673}-1= k(t)(t^2+1)+q(t)$$
where $q$ is first degree polynomial $q(t)=at+b$, where $a,b$ are clearly real. Now plug $t=i$ in equation in order to find $a$ and $b$:

$$ i-1 = k(i)\cdot 0 +ai+b\implies a=1 \;\;\;{\rm and}\;\;\;b=-1$$

Since $p(x) = q(t) = x^3-1$ we are done, $p(3)=26$.

Answer (score 4):

You can write $x^{2019} - 1$ in the form:

$$x^{2019} - 1 = x^{2013} (x^6 + 1) - x^{2013} - 1$$

and $x^{2013}$ can be written in the form:

$$x^{2013} - 1 = x^{2007} (x^6 + 1) - x^{2007} - 1$$
$$\Rightarrow x^{2019} - 1  = x^{2013} (x^6 + 1) - \left(x^{2007} (x^6 + 1) - x^{2007}\right) - 1$$
$$= (x^6 + 1)(x^{2013} - x^{2007})+ x^{2007}-1$$

Each time this process is applied, you can isolate $x^{n - 12}$ from $x^{n}$, where $n$ is a natural number. Does this help with understanding the explanation in the comments?

After every multiple of $x^{12}$, the sign of the remainder term is unchanged. This justifies the remainder as being $x^3 - 1$ instead of $-(x^3 - 1)$. This is separate from the quotient $x^{2013} - x^{2007} + x^{2001} \cdots$ where the signs do indeed alternate.

Answer (score 1):

As $12|2016$, then $x^{12}-1|x^{2016}-1$, and because $x^{12}-1=(x^6-1)(x^6+1)$ we have $x^6+1|x^{2016}-1$.

Therefore $x^6+1|x^3(x^{2016}-1)=x^{2019}-x^3$, which gives the remainder when $x^6+1$ divides $x^{2019}-1$ as $x^3-1$.

$(x-3)^3=x^3-9x^2+27x-27$ which implies $0\equiv x^3-27 \pmod{x-3}$ as $-9x^2+27x=-9x(x-3)$.

So $x-3|x^3-27$ and as $x^3-1=x^3-27+26$, and the final remainder is $26$.